# Method for maximizing simple functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am wondering if there is a general method or approach to maximizing ( or minimizing) multivariable functions.

For example, consider $f(x,y)=49+4x-x^2-2y^2$
over   $\mathbb R^{2}$

Now, it could be seen just by looking what the answer would be, but I want to make sure I have a general method.

I am wondering if my reasoning is correct or if anyone has suggestions/hints etc.

My first thought is, to make some general ideas, and note that because of the $-x^2-2y^{2}$, at large values of x and y we will have negative values, so this indicates our max value will most likely be in some sort of disk, with say radius r with $\{x^2+y^2 \le r^2\}$

Next, completing the square and writing $f(x,y)=49+4-(x-2)^2-2y^2$

ie, if $$x^2+y^2 \ge r^2 \rightarrow (x-2)^2+y^2 \ge (r-2)^2 \rightarrow (x-2)^2+2y^2 \ge (r-2)^2 \rightarrow f(x,y) \le 53-(r-2)^2$$ which by choosing any r, say r=10 we can say that any r outside the disk is negative, and because even taking f(0,0) is positive, we are restrained to the disk?

Next I could just solve for the zeros of the partial derivatives etc,

but I am mostly wondering about the generality/approach/validity of the first part.

Thanks

Comment: Why even bother with the initial step? Why not just look at the partial derivatives first? Your example, for instance, the first derivatives readily yield $(x,y)=(2,0)$, and a second derivative test confirms this is a local maximum. The function is concave, so it is indeed a global maximum.

Comment: @MichaelGrant but will this always be a case? We have no covered second derivative test

Comment: There are lots of conditions one has to contend with when doing multivariate optimization. But I would suggest that artificially restricting yourself to a disk like this really isn't helping things along. It's a distraction. It sounds like you have some more concepts to learn about optimality conditions, so don't get too far ahead of yourself.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method $1$:

$f(x,y) = 53 - (x-2)^2 - 2y^2 \leq 53 \to f_{\text{max}} = 53$ at $x = 2, y = 0$.

Method $2$:

$f_x = 0 = f_y \to -2x+4 = 0 = -4y \to x = 2, y = 0 \to (2,0)$ is the only critical point. Next $f_{xx} = -2 < 0 \to (2,0)$ is a relative maxima of $f$, and $f_{\text{max}} = f(2,0) = 53$.

Comment: Thank you, but I was not having to much trouble with the problem itself, more so looking for general approach. Can you elaborate on what the second derivative can tell us?